# Best practices for database comunication layer for SQL Server and .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, nhibernate, ado.net, data-access-layer

I have been asked to implement in a couple of hours a new ASP.NET application that has to access a SQL Server database.

I am wondering what is the best (and quickest) method to access the database, a good practice is to create a data access layer but how would you create this?

1. Using ADO.NET and creating a method `runQuery(query,parameters)` and than a single method for each query, like:

   ```
   getRowByID(id){
      runQuery("SELECT..",id);
   }

   getRowsByDate(date){
      runQuery("SELECT..",date);
   }
   ```
2. Using the built in wizards in Visual Studio? (horrible solution but very quick)
3. Using something like nHibernate, Linq or...?

I personally would go for the first method that is not too complicated, I don't like auto generated code so I would drop the second, maybe the third??

Let me know what you think and if you have any valid example.

Thank you

Comment: EF should be very quick and easy

Comment: IMO it boils down to how many experiences you have with each of the 3 options.

Comment: I would only ever use option #3 - gives you a nice object-based programming interface in your code, and leaves all the gory details to the ORM. #1 is **horribly bad** (*one method for everything*), and I'm not sure what you mean by #2 ....

Comment: If you don't want any *generated code* (why ever.....), and you're comfortable with straight SQL statements, have a look at [Dapper Dot Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) - a micro-ORM that's used e.g. on this very site here. Very simple, very fast, very versatile - works with direct SQL statements, no visual model designer or any of that.....

Comment: @marc_s I agree with you about #3, about #2: I mean something like this [VS Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581776.aspx). But why do you think #1 is bad? there would be a method that handle the actual comunication with the DB and other methods that use it passing the right query string and parameters... it looks clean to me (it is based on this function [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx#_SqlClient) but separating the part with the query string from the code that actually connects to the db... (Thanks for your help)

Answer (score 1):

> getRowByID(id){ 
>   getRowsByDate(date){

Two lines to fire you. Use an ORM. Use something that supports LINQ. If you want something fast and lightweight use BLToolkit.

> 2.Using the built in wizards in Visual Studio

Fired again.

> 3.Using something like nHibernate, Linq or...?

Exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do agree that #3 is the best method but I don't get why #1 is so wrong...? Thank you

Comment: Because you end up with mre and mor emethods for every possible query osmoene may need to write. This is an anti pattern - over time this becomes a non-maintainable beast.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer stored procedures.  They're fast and easy to test, parameterized values plug in easily, and in case something goes wrong it's really easy to test for by executing the SP directly.  Also easy to make changes later, as well as use default null parameters and such.  Are you mostly/only doing SELECT queries?

Answer (score 1):

Do option 3 and just use **BLToolkit**, here is a link -> http://www.bltoolkit.net/Doc.Linq.ashx
Just check out the Demo Project

If you want to have a simple abstraction choose BLToolkit, certainly not EF

Answer (score 0):

If I need to bang out an application quickly that uses a database - I use Linq to Sql.  It's just simple and clean.

Answer (score 0):

So, as @TomTom said, using an ORM like Entity Framework plus LINQ is a very quick manner to access the database, and it lets your application very flexible in the sense that you could easily change the background database without changing a line in the data-access layer (you would just change the provider to the right one).

Of course using ORMs will mean that you'll get autogenerated code somehow, and it will certainly not be as fast as if you were writing your code by hand. BUt still this is the fastest solution you will find concerning data access provided by Microsoft so far.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use EF or Linq to SQL. Quick and first. And I don't need to write SQL statements in code. As it is one of the object of Language Integrated Query(LINQ). I also like Intelliense of Visual Studio showing table name, column names in LINQ and it reduce my debugging time as well.